# How to effectively transfer a price value between forms from one page to another

Tags: php, html, forms

Basically what I have is 4 pages in this order

1. form1.php
2. form2.php
3. form3.php
4. form4.php

Each page contains a form with an Html select option, and at the bottom of every form, is a text view which displays a price, the price changes based on what options you select, then a Next Button that takes you to the next page is also located at the bottom of the form

What I am trying to achieve here is once i click the next button, the current price being displayed in the text field gets transferred to the next form as the base price, until the user gets to the final Page

And yes i have read about cookies and sessions, as well as POST and GET Methods, but i can't figure out how to implement it and also don't know which method would be better to handle such issue

**The html of the first page with the jquery calculating the price**

```js
var basePrice = 0;

$(".calculate").change(function() {
    newPrice = basePrice;
    
    $('.calculate option:selected').each(function() {
        newPrice += $(this).data('price')
    });
    
    $('#item-price').html(newPrice);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm" role="form" method="POST" action="form2.php" >

                      <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                          <select class="calculate diff " id="service" name="serv"  required>
                            <option data-price="0" value="0">Choose A Service </option>
                            <option data-price="0" value="1">Airport Shuttle</option>                      
                          </select>
                             
                      </div>

                       <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                          <select class="calculate diff" id="airport" name="arpt" required>
                          <option data-price="0" value="0">Pick an Airport </option>
                          <option data-price="6000" value="1">MM1</option>
                          <option data-price="5900" value="2">MM2</option>
                          
                          </select>
                             
                      </div>

                  <div class="col-md-12 row" style="margin-top:-20px">
                    <h4 class="price">Price Estimate: ₦<span id="item-price" name="price" >0</span></h4>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6" >
                        <a href="form2.php">
                      <button style="float:right;" type="submit" class="button2">
                      <span><span>NEXT</span></span></button></a>
                    </div>

                    </form>
```

the consecutive pages have similar forms

so if MM1 was selected in page one and next button was clicked, 6000 should automatically be in the page 2 price text

What is the best method to implement this with, and how can i properly do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store the data in a local session by sending it to a controller before loading the second form, this would mean using a submit listener on your form and then firing up an AJAX request to some sort of controller. You could then access the data on form 2.

This would only work if the next button was of type submit, other-wise, perhaps use `.click(function() {});` instead.

## JavaScript

```
(function ($) {
    $('form').submit(function() {
        $.post('/some/form/controller', { price: $('#item-price').html() }, function(response) {
            return true;
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

## PHP Controller

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['price'] = $_POST['price'] ?? 0; # PHP 7+

# Pointed out by @FunkFortyNiner
$_SESSION['price'] = isset($_POST['price']) ? $_POST['price'] : 0; #PHP 5.6+
```

## Form 2/3/4

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<h1>£<?= $_SESSION['price']; ?></h1>
```

If this method is too prolonging, perhaps consider making the price a disabled input field when calculating or a hidden input field and just POST all the data to the next form which can be accessed via `$_POST[]` and the input `name=".."` as the index.

Comment: Note that the `??` null coalescing operator is only available in PHP 7+ http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner well noted, `isset($_POST['price']) ? $_POST['price'] : 0` can be used instead.

Comment: @Jaquarh @FunkFortyNiner `<h1>£<?= $_SESSION['price']; ?></h1>` passes '0' in form2 instead of the price value from form1

Comment: `var_dump($_POST)` and see if it contains the correct value, if not, `console.log($('#item-price').html())` and see if it is getting the correct value @Drwho

Comment: Strange because `console.log($('#item-price').html());` for me is returning 6000 @Drwho

Comment: could we enter a chat or something so i can show you exactly what i am doing, perhaps i'm doing something wrong? @Jaquarh

Comment: i don't have enough reputation to chat @Jaquarh

Comment: @Drwho You can see it working on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hxzkcr71/). You need to post the data to a PHP file using an AJAX request which creates / stores the price into a session before changing to form 2

Comment: but i also noticed that the price value of form 2 doesn't send to form 3 instead it sends form1 price values to all the forms

Comment: i just added the initial javascript function to other pages

Comment: You can use different params in your session for multiple prices, or append to it @Drwho